# ZF2 saving to multiple tables

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have a mapper class, `OrganizationMapper` that saves data to multiple tables with the `save` method. The `save` method looks like this:

```
public function save(OrganizationInterface $organization) {
        $action = new Insert('TABLE NAME');
        $action->values([<SOME VALUES>]);
        $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
        $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $action1 = new Insert('OTHER TABLE NAME');
        $action1->values([OTHER VALUES]);
        $sql1 = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
        $stmt1   = $sql1->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action1);
        $result1 = $stmt1->execute();
        ...
}
```

There are a couple more cycles of `$action#`, `$sql#`, `$stmt#`, `$result#`.

How can I avoid these repetitive cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicate code create an additional method, let's call it `insertIntoTable()`. This method will be an auxiliary function for inserting data into a certain table:

```
public function save(OrganizationInterface $organization) {
        $result = $this->insertIntoTable('TABLE NAME', $values);

        $result1 = $this->insertIntoTable('OTHER TABLE NAME', $values1);
        ...
}

private function insertIntoTable($tableName = "", $values) {
        $action = new Insert($tableName);
        $action->values($values);
        $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
        $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($action);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        return $result;
}
```

Comment: best ideas are always dead simple :-)